# Tem como criar uma ExpandableListView com o efeito de swipe?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Eu tenho uma `ListView` que é composta de 3 `ListView's` encadeadas. A primeira é uma lista de Ano de lançamento, que possui uma lista de gêneros que por sua vez armazena uma lista de filmes. Queria ter a opção de expandir e contrair as listas pelo ano e gênero dos filmes.
Eu já fiz os `Adapter's` para o Swipe e utilizei essa biblioteca: 
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Pelo que eu li, eu preciso ter uma label e expandir a lista a partir dela, mas no meu caso, a label vai ser um item da `ListView` "pai".
Fiz um protótipo da tela pra ficar mais fácil de visualizar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A funcionalidade do `Swipe` vai existir apenas na lista de filmes. Então o meu Adapter der filmes estende `BaseSwipeAdapter`, só que como quero que seja uma lista Expansível, teria que estender `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

AdaptadorFilme.java:

```
public class AdaptadorFilme extends BaseSwipeAdapter {
String [] nomeFilme
int [] imgFilme;
Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public AdaptadorFilme(Context context, int[] imgFilme,String[] nomeFilme) {
    this.nomeFilme = nomeFilme;
    this.imgFilme = imgFilme;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return nomeFilme.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imgFilme;
    TextView nomeFilme;
    SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    SwipeLayout item;
}

@Override
public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
    return R.id.swipeProd;
}

@Override
public View generateView(final int position, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    final Holder h;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_filmes, null);
        h = new Holder();
        h.imgFilme = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
        h.nomeFilme = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        h.swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) v.findViewById(getSwipeLayoutResourceId(position));

        h.imgFilme.setImageResource(imgFilme[position]);
        h.nomeFilme.setText(nomeFilme[position]);

    h.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {

        }
    });
    return v;
}


@Override
public void fillValues(int position, View convertView) {

}
```

}

AdaptadorGenero.java

```
public class AdaptadorGenero extends BaseAdapter {
final Holder h = new Holder();
String[] nomeFilme;
int []imgFilme;
Context context;
AdaptadorFilmes adaptadorFilmesActivity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public AdaptadorGenero(int tipoAdap,String[] nomeFilme, String[] nomeGenero, String[] precosProdutos, int[] imgFilme, int[] qtd, Context context) {
    this.nomeFilme = nomeFilme;
    this.imgFilme = imgFilme;
    this.context = context;
    this.adaptadorFilmesActivity =  new AdaptadorFilmes(context,imgFilme,nomeFilme);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imgFilme.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder{
    TextView nomeGenero;
    ImageView setinha;
    ListView listaFilmes;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_cat,null);
    h.nomeGenero = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nomeitem);
    h.setinha = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.setinha); 
    h.nomeGenero.setText(nomeGenero[position]);
    h.listaFilmes.setAdapter(adaptadorFilmesActivity);

    calculeHeightListView();
    return v;
}

private void calculeHeightListView() {
    int totalHeight = 0;
    ListAdapter adapter = h.listaFilmes.getAdapter();
    int lenght = adapter.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, h.listaFilmes);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = h.listaFilmes.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (h.listaFilmes.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
    h.listaFilmes.setLayoutParams(params);
    h.listaFilmes.requestLayout();
}
```

}

O adaptador de Ano segue a mesma ideia do de gênero.
Como faço para que ao clicar na setinha da `ListView` "pai" a `ListView` "filho" seja exibida/escondida?

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive um problema similar ao seu, e consegui resolver usando um RecyclerView e um adapter customizado. Consegui fazer me baseando na biblioteca [android-advancedrecyclerview](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) e fui mudando o que precisava para o meu projeto.

para o seu, para o seu caso, acredito que o [Expandable & Draggable & Swiping](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/master/example/src/main/java/com/h6ah4i/android/example/advrecyclerview/demo_eds) resolva o seu problema.

Fragment com a chamada da ExpandableListView e a criação do Adapter

```
ExpandableDraggableSwipeableExampleFragment
```

Adapter que faz o controle do swipe (e também do drag) que permite excluir a linha após expandir o ELV

```
ExpandableDraggableSwipeableExampleAdapter
```

Dentro do adapter você tem métodos específicos para controlar o swipe do "pai"

```
@Override
    public SwipeResultAction onSwipeGroupItem(MyGroupViewHolder holder, int groupPosition, int result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSwipeGroupItem(groupPosition = " + groupPosition + ", result = " + result + ")");
    switch (result) {
        // swipe right
        case Swipeable.RESULT_SWIPED_RIGHT:
            if (mProvider.getGroupItem(groupPosition).isPinned()) {
                // pinned --- back to default position
                return new GroupUnpinResultAction(this, groupPosition);
            } else {
                // not pinned --- remove
                return new GroupSwipeRightResultAction(this, groupPosition);
            }
            // swipe left -- pin
        case Swipeable.RESULT_SWIPED_LEFT:
            return new GroupSwipeLeftResultAction(this, groupPosition);
        // other --- do nothing
        case Swipeable.RESULT_CANCELED:
        default:
            if (groupPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                return new GroupUnpinResultAction(this, groupPosition);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
    }
}
```

e do "filho"

```
@Override
public SwipeResultAction onSwipeChildItem(MyChildViewHolder holder, int groupPosition, int childPosition, int result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSwipeChildItem(groupPosition = " + groupPosition + ", childPosition = " + childPosition + ", result = " + result + ")");

    switch (result) {
        // swipe right
        case Swipeable.RESULT_SWIPED_RIGHT:
            if (mProvider.getChildItem(groupPosition, childPosition).isPinned()) {
                // pinned --- back to default position
                return new ChildUnpinResultAction(this, groupPosition, childPosition);
            } else {
                // not pinned --- remove
                return new ChildSwipeRightResultAction(this, groupPosition, childPosition);
            }
            // swipe left -- pin
        case Swipeable.RESULT_SWIPED_LEFT:
            return new ChildSwipeLeftResultAction(this, groupPosition, childPosition);
        // other --- do nothing
        case Swipeable.RESULT_CANCELED:
        default:
            if (groupPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                return new ChildUnpinResultAction(this, groupPosition, childPosition);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
    }
}
```